# Making a Promise on god and not keeping it

Tags: vedas

I once made a promise to another person in the name of god. I promised to the person by keeping my right hand on god’s picture in phone. Now I am unable to keep my promise. I cant keep that promise and I keep breaking it often. What is the consequence and is there any ritual for this. I once read its ok to lie to your wife to save marriage. Is it true.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Assuming it isn’t anything too bad, maybe just explain that you made a mistake ? And apologies. (And then just be really careful to make only promises you could keep in future.)